# Why does `scrapy` stop working after parsing the first URL?

Tags: python, scrapy

Below is my code in `python` to crawl a website with multiple pages. It starts to crawl the website `https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/top.json?sort=top&limit=25/` then if there is a `after` field in the response, it will `yield` another request. But what is happening is that the `scrapy` stops working after the first request.

```
import scrapy
import json

class RedditJsonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reddit_json'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com/r/movies/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/top.json?sort=top&limit=25/']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        print('length:', len(jsonresponse['data']['children']))

        for item in jsonresponse['data']['children']:
            info = {
                'title': item['data']['title']
            }
            yield info

        after = jsonresponse['data']['after']
        print('after=', after)
        if after:
            next_page = response.url + '&after=' + after
            print('next page, ', next_page)
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
        else:
            print('no more pages')
```

The last few lines of the code is as below. It prints `next page` but before that you can see `Spider closed (finished)` in the log. It seems that the scrapy stops the second request. How can I make it work with multiple requests?

```
2019-07-22 12:17:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
/length:
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 22, 2, 17, 41, 169719),
 'item_scraped_count': 25,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 28,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 51044352,
 'memusage/startup': 51044352,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 22, 2, 17, 36, 462945)}
2019-07-22 12:17:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
length: 25
after= t3_cfv6xt
next page,  https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/top.json?sort=top&limit=25/&after=t3_cfv6xt
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging and I found this is caused by a wrong value in `allowed_domains` field. It can be fixed by changing:

```
allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com/r/movies/']
```

to

```
allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
```